# How do I fix this OverflowError?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I keep getting a "OverflowError: math range error". No matter what I input, the result is the same. I'm running Python 3.3, and it's finding the problem at the last line. How do I fix this? (Also, I don't want to hear anything about my overuse of parentheses. It is my preference for there to be this many.):

```
import math

a=float(input('a=?'))
b=float(input('b=?'))
c=float(input('c=?'))
d=float(input('d=?'))

critical_point_n=((-2*b)-math.sqrt(abs((4*(math.pow(b, 2)))-(12*a*c))))/(6*a)

first_root=critical_point_n-1

if first_root==0 and c==0:
    first_root+=(-0.01)

for x in range(10):
    first_root=first_root-((a*(math.pow(first_root, 3)))+(b*(math.pow(first_root, 2))+(c*first_root)+d)/(3*(a*(math.pow(first_root, 2))))+(2*(b*first_root))+c)
```

Comment: That iteration looks divergent to me.  Are you sure that's the expression you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you don't want to hear about your excessive use of parenthesis, but the problem is that you have the parenthesis in the wrong places. With the sheer number of parenthesis you used, it took a while to find the problem.

I think the following code is much cleaner, easier to debug, and vastly easier to maintain in the future. I also included what I think is the corrected version of your one-liner.

```
import math

a=float(input('a=?'))
b=float(input('b=?'))
c=float(input('c=?'))
d=float(input('d=?'))

critical_point_n=((-2*b)-math.sqrt(abs((4*(math.pow(b, 2)))-(12*a*c))))/(6*a)

first_root=critical_point_n-1

if first_root==0 and c==0:
    first_root+=(-0.01)

for x in range(10):
    f = a*first_root**3 + b*first_root**2 + c*first_root + d
    fp = 3*a*first_root**2 + 2*b*first_root + c
    first_root = first_root - (f/fp)
    #first_root=first_root-(((a*(math.pow(first_root, 3)))+(b*(math.pow(first_root, 2))+(c*first_root)+d)))/((3*(a*(math.pow(first_root, 2))))+(2*(b*first_root))+c)
    print(first_root)
```

Comment: I tried your code, and somehow all the errors I got disappeared. It all works now. However, I still don't understand how putting the code in this form erased the errors.

Comment: @user2442129: it's not that the errors were magically erased, it's that your expression isn't the same as this one.  It's not in a different form, it's a different formula entirely.  casevh's version is `(a*first_root**3 + b*first_root**2 + c*first_root + d)/(3*a*first_root**2 + 2*b*first_root + c)`.  Yours is `2*b*first_root + c + (a*first_root**3 + b*first_root**2 + c*first_root + d)/(3*a*first_root**2)`, which diverges.  As casevh notes, you didn't see the problem because of all the parentheses you didn't want anyone to mention.

Comment: (I'm using x instead of first_root, and ^ for exponentiation.) Because you had parenthesis in the wrong locations, you were evaluating: `x - a*x^3 + (b*x^2+c*x+d)/(3*a*x^2) + 2*b*x + c` You wanted `x - (a*x^3 + b*x^2+c*x+d)/(3*a*x^2 + 2*b*x + c)` but you didn't have the parenthesis in the correct locations. The formula you were evaluating was not correct for convergence with Newton's method. Splitting the function evaluation across multiple lines is less prone to errors than using parenthesis.

Comment: Wow... I can't believe I didn't notice that earlier. I'm so stupid.

Answer (score 2):

You are overflowing the internal representation of `float`s. Use `sys.float_info` to check your system's limits for floating point numbers. http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/sys.html#sys.float_info

I recommend trying out your operations by "hand" on wolframalpha to see the magnitude of the actual values. http://www.wolframalpha.com/

Answer (score 1):

The `math` range of functions work on `doubles`... so you're out of range for that - re-write as normal Python floats which will scale as needs be, or look at using `decimal.Decimal` which also has `sqrt`, `power` etc.. functions: http://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: What's a double in Python? And no, ``float()`` won't grow to infinity.

Comment: @lqc good point about `float` growing - in regards to the former, I believe that Python's `float` is basically a C `double`