# Python OverflowError: math range error

Tags: python, math, overflow

I get an Overflow error when i try this calculation,

```
output=math.exp(1391.12694245)*100
```

i know this happens because that the number used is 'outside  the range of a double'.
but is there any way for solving this and getting the value of output.
Can someone please help?

Comment: its infinity value ryt..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16905023/478656 - use `from decimal import Decimal; Decimal(1391.12694245).exp()*100`

Comment: Can you give more information about the problem you're trying to solve? The normal `float` range is more than enough for most real-world tasks, and using extended precision is usually the wrong solution - it may be that you simply need to reformulate your calculation to avoid the overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use extra precision floating point numbers from numpy:

```
import numpy as np
np.exp(np.array([1391.12694245],dtype=np.float128))*100
# array([ 1.4413011e+606], dtype=float128)
```

Comment: This is platform specific: `float128` isn't available on all platforms (and usually isn't a 128-bit floating-point type even when it *is* present).